# Embed spread sheet to chrome browser that is from onenote get api

Tags: excel, html, google-chrome, onenote

I am trying get page content from One note API to render content in browser .the API returning content in html format. the spread sheet is getting with the object tag.but the object tag is not rendering in browser and getting an error plug in not supported.

May i know how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

This was one of our top requested features - see our uservoice:
https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/7916235-ability-to-get-pre-auth-d-image-urls-from-a-onenot

And our blog post:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2016/03/22/693/

Basically, just append the query param

```
?preAuthenticated=true
```

to the request that gets page content.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I am getting the content url's by using the preAuthenticated=true. But my question is i am getting the content url with the object tag in that some of are pdf , images and spread sheet files .The retrieved object tag are rendering into the browser except spread sheet .for that in the place of spreadsheet object tag i am getting an alert image plugin not supported. so my question is render spread sheet object tag into browser? and my object tag is looks like this

Comment: <object data-attachment="Testing from drive  - Spreadsheet.xlsx" type="application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" data="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/resources/0-b647d10da1b3411383f695cd613c7138!1-AC701DC279BF55F1!134/content?publicAuth=true&amp;mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" title="undefined"></object>

Comment: We simply use the object tag as a means of communication in the API. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

Comment: If you want it to be renderable, I suggest translating the object tag to an anchor tag "<a href=...>"